# Can node-config reload configurations without restarting Node?

Tags: node.js

I'm using [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) for configs in my Node app. One of the configurations I'm managing is a super-secret password that even I am not allowed to know. To handle this I've implemented a web app that a user can use to update the password in production without me being in the loop.

What I want to do is have the Node application modify the local.json config file and then tell config to reload configurations so that this configuration takes place without having to close and relaunch the Node application.

Is there a way to do that, or is restarting Node the only option for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the answer in this thread:

https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/34

After updating the config file you can force config to reload with this line:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('config')];
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: I know this is a bit old but I cam across this now.
You need also to re-require the config module which means you also need a line like 
`var config = require('config');` 
after the delete