# Live updating Node.js logging configuration

Tags: node.js, logging, configuration, devops, configuration-files

What I'm trying to accomplish:
Update the logging level on a node micro service, without stopping the existing running service, by detecting the saving of a change to the config file.

The reason: work policies demand different levels of approval based on what gets changed.
Updating a config file is a "standard change" (considered "safe", requiring low ceremony to accomplish.)
Changing the config file, and restarting the service is a "normal change" (considered "not safe", requiring vp approval).
This capability will go a long way towards allowing us to improve the logging in our services.

The technical challenge:
Both node-config and bunyan appear to require a restart in order to accept changes.
Results of attempting to do proper research prior to submitting a question:
[Live updating Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786875/live-updating-node-js-server/30787771)
[Can node-config reload configurations without restarting Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974297/can-node-config-reload-configurations-without-restarting-node)
(This last post has a solution that worked for someone, but I couldn't get it to work.)
In theory, I should be able to delete both the app level objects using the lines:

delete require.cache[require.resolve('config')];
delete require.cache[require.resolve('logging')];

and then recreate both objects with the new configurations read from the changed config file.
Deleting the config and logging object may work, but I'm still a node nube so every way that I attempted to use this magical line failed for me.
(Caveat: I was able to delete the objects I just couldn't get them recreated in such a way that my code would use the newly created objects.)

The horrifically ugly attempt of what I'm doing can be found on my github in the "spike_LiveUpdate" directory of:
https://github.com/MalcolmAnderson/uService_stub

The only thing we are attempting to change is the log level of the application so that, if we needed to, we could:
bounce the logging level "to 11" for a small handful of minutes,
have the user demonstrate their error,
and the put it back to the normal logging level.

(It would also be a useful tool to have in our back pocket so when the dealers of FUD say, "But if you get the logging level wrong, we will have to use an emergency change to fix it.  Sorry, we appreciate your desire to get a better picture of what's happening in the application, but we just can't justify the risk you're proposing.")

Research prior to writing question:
Attempt to solve the problem.
Search for "node live update", "node live configuration update", "node no restart configuration change"
Search for the above but replacing the word "live update" with "rolling update" (this got a lot of Kubernetes hits, which may be the way I have to go with this.)

Bottom line:  Attempting to be able to change both Node-config, and Bunyan logging without a restart.
[For all I know, there's a security reason for not allowing live updates.]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand truly, you need to change log level of your application but without restart it

According to this, there are couple of ways I can suggest.

- You can create a second server which includes the new deployment of your changed code and route new traffic to the new server and stop routing new traffic to the old server. When old server drains the processes it currently has, you can shut it down and go with a new one, or re-deploy your application for normal status.
- You can create a second application layer in the same server with different port which I do not recommend it and do the same thing with first bullet that I mentioned.

If you're not running on Kubernetes, you need to make your own rolling update strategy (k8s is doing it automatically).

Comment: Hi zenka, thank you for your answer.  Help me understand how your solution does not involve shutting down a running node service in order to change its configuration.

Comment: As I explained, the first thing you must do, creating a new server and routing all new traffic to that one. And drain the current traffic to old one gracefully. In that way nobody will feel anything, it is not going to effect user's experience.

Comment: Hi, again, thanks for answering the question.  What I originally said my goal was is to "Update the logging level on a node micro service, without restarting the service, by detecting the saving of a change to the config file." The stress is on the "without restarting the service." Any solution that involves shutting down the service does not fulfill the purpose of the question. I edited the statement to say, "without shutting down the running service."

Comment: It's not possible to change config without restarting the app. I'm just saying an alternative solution.